# Javascript not loading html into divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

Why this doesn't work? It's supposed to load content of another html file into DIV with bottom id

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
　　<head>
　　　　<script type="text/javascript">
function loadContent(href, container){
　　$wrapper = $('<div>'); 
　　$wrapper.addClass('loaded_content_wrapper').appendTo(container).load(href, function(){
　　　　$(this).animate({marginLeft:0}, 'slow').prevAll().animate({marginLeft:'-100%'}, 'slow', function(){
　　　　　　$(this).remove();
　　　　});
　　})
}
　　　　</script>
　　<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
　　</head>

<div onClick="loadContent('hello-world.html', $('#bottom'))">Home</div>
<div id="bottom">
ramkaramka
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Just so you know, you're missing the <body> tags

Comment: @DavidThomas I don't see anything there which would run before DOM ready. All DOM querying code is contained within function bodies...

Answer (score 1):

It worked if add script tag for jquery.js and set jquery.js , hello-world.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function loadContent(href, container){
    $wrapper = $('<div>'); 
    $wrapper.addClass('loaded_content_wrapper').appendTo(container).load(href, function(){
        $(this).animate({marginLeft:0}, 'slow').prevAll().animate({marginLeft:'-100%'}, 'slow', function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    })
}
        </script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

<div onClick="loadContent('hello-world.html', $('#bottom'))">Home</div>
<div id="bottom">
ramkaramka
</div>

</html>
```